# Windows 8 Store App Sliding Panel

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am working on a Windows 8 Store App. I want to use sliding panel for my application such as facebook mobile application leftside menu or rightside friends list. What am i want to do ? When i click to button panel should open left 0 to right side about 300px but i didn't find any solution for this. Can you help me for this ? Thx inadvance.

I SOLVED

Actually, I don't want to work with scrollview i want to show a setting pane. I solved my problem with using settingflyout. So, you can use basicly in your project. Add new item >> add settingflyout. But thx for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScrollViewer
    x:Name="HorizontalScrollViewer"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
    ZoomMode="Disabled"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
    HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Near"
    HorizontalSnapPointsType="Mandatory">
    <StackPanel
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid
            x:Name="LeftPanel">
            ...
        </Grid>
        <Grid
            x:Name="CenterPanel">
            <ListView .../>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
            x:Name="RightPanel">
            ...
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Actually, i solved with using settingflyout which i added to project as new item but i dont get left side of the app.. Is there any idea. I tried to change horizantal alighment but not happened anything.